# Can't send SMS; getting 500 error in Java/Scala Google Voice API

Tags: java, scala, voip, google-voice

I've got this code:

```
val voice = new Voice("<un>", "<pw>")
voice.login()
// The ID isn't specced well in the source code, not sure what it needs to be
voice.sendSMS("<number>", "hello", "343434")
```

I'm getting this error thrown in the browser (Play 2.0):

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://www.google.com/voice/b/0/sms/send/]
```

The stacktrace is:

```
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[info] application - index:
https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin - OK
Logged in to Google - Auth token received
https://www.google.com/voice/b/0/settings/tab/phones - OK
https://www.google.com/voice/b/0 - OK
Successfully Received rnr_se.
smsdata: id=hello&phoneNumber=XXXXXXXX&conversationId=343434&text=hello&_rnr_se=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[error] application - 

! @6an08o8h8 - Internal server error, for request [GET /smsTest] ->

play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://www.google.com/voice/b/0/sms/send/]]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:311) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.1]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:619) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.1]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:196) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.1]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://www.google.com/voice/b/0/sms/send/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234) ~[na:1.6]
    at com.techventus.server.voice.Voice.sendSMS(Voice.java:1669) ~[google-voice-java-1.14.jar:na]
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$smsTest$1.apply(Application.scala:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$smsTest$1.apply(Application.scala:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:170) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.1]
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/franklovecchio/Desktop/dev/applications-voip/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
```

I'm using [the latest jar](https://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/downloads/detail?name=google-voice-java-1.14-java6.jar).

Is there anybody that can send an SMS currently?

Comment: What's the rest of the error page response?

Comment: Sorry, updated for stack trace.

Comment: Does sending an SMS work as a simple Java app (as on the voice API web page)?

Comment: Paul, I'm not sure I understand the question - the Play! route only has a few lines of code (what's listed above), you can see that Voice.java is throwing the error, so that's where the problem lies!

Comment: It's erroring in the play code. I'm suggesting trying a smaller test case, without Play, just Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON Spray which is built on top of Akka. you would need the following imports among many others:

```
import java.io._;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.mail._;
import javax.mail.internet._;
import javax.activation._;
import cc.spray.json._
```

Basically the pseudocode or algorithm is identical to what you would have for an implementation in Java, only you would be coding in Scala.

Twitter's finagle is a good backbone for your server requests and responses.